# How to programatically notify WSO2 ESB about disconnected endpoint?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have an ESB that interacts with core module via TCP. For high availability, I deployed 2 core module nodes and used a LoadBalance Endpoint to configure these nodes in ESB. I also wrote my own TCP Sender that extends AbstractTransportSender class to send message to core nodes.

My question is: when my TCP Sender detects that one node is disconnected, how can it programmatically notify ESB about that to stop sending messages to this node after several fail tries?

Comment: Anyone faced the same problem as mine?

Comment: If you are using load balancing endpoint wso2 will stop sending to the disconnected node

Comment: But how can WSO2 know about disconnected node? My TCP Sender has to notify WSO2 about that, right?